# Select Range within Row of Active Cell

Tags: excel, vba, range, offset

I've seen several other questions similar to mine and I've tried several different solutions but I am still getting strange results.  My code finds a value in another workbook in Column AA, then I want to copy that row from Column C to Column BC and paste in current workbook.  All of the code works except copying from column C to BC.  For some reason it starts copying the row from column AC.  I've tried a standard range but I think it's relative from the active cell and I don't know if there is a way to do negative column letters so then I tried Offset and I tried .Cells but none select the correct range.  Here is a couple of examples of the code I've tried:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim checknum As String
Dim chkrow As String
Dim Rng As Range

prfile1 = Worksheets("setup").Range("B10").Value
prfile2 = Worksheets("setup").Range("B7").Value
filepath = Worksheets("setup").Range("e10").Value

checknum = ComboBox1.Value

'Workbooks.Open filepath & prfile2
Windows(prfile2).Activate
Worksheets("MRegister").Select

With Worksheets("MRegister").Range("AA:AA")
    Set Rng = .Find(What:=checknum, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
            Rng.Select
            .Range(.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, -24), .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 28)).Select
            Selection.Copy
End With

Windows(prfile1).Activate
Sheets("ReprintOld").Range("M203:BM203").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Windows(prfile2).Activate
Sheets("MRegister").Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Sheets("ReprintOld").Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

for Offset:

```
.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28)).Select
```

for standard Range:

```
.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row & ":BC" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
```

You would think all of these would work, but they all start the selection several columns to the right of the active cell.

Comment: You could just use: `Intersect(Rg.Entirerow, .Range("C:BC")).Copy`

Comment: I like the simplicity of that, but like all of the others I've tried, it also copies from `AC:CC`.  It's very strange.

Comment: Copying the entire row works, but any type of range is weird.

Comment: I didn't see you had a Range on the end of the With block. You'd need: `Intersect(Rg.Entirerow, .Worksheet.Range("C:BC")).Copy`

Comment: That worked great! Ty.  post it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.  Now can you go through the rest of my 40 pages of code and simplify all of it for me?? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, as has been mentioned by user3561813, the fact that you have a Range object on the end of your `With` statement. Perhaps the simplest solution would be to use:

```
Intersect(Rng.Entirerow, .Worksheet.Range("C:BC")).Copy
```

Comment: just a note...the variable is `Rng` not `Rg`.  I tried to edit the answer but it requires editing 10 characters

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this line: `.Range(.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, -24), .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 28)).Select`

Because the `With` statement references `With Worksheets("MRegister").Range("AA:AA")`, it's trying to find the `.Range` property of the Column "AA".

If you rewrite it to something like  `Worksheets("MRegister").Range(.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, -24), .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 28)).Select`, it should work.

Comment: I has a similar issue, I kept getting an error with .Cells, so I used Worksheets("MRegister").Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, -24), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 28)).Select and this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this after the .Find:

Rng.offset(0,3-rng.column).resize(1,53).copy

Rng is a reference to the cell with the desired checknum, offset that zero rows and back to column C, then resize it to 1 row by 53 columns (C to BC) and copy it.

You should check that the find worked before the copy:

If not rng is nothing then

You don’t need the select

Comment: this is an interesting method of range.  Rory's answer also doesn't require the select and you don't need to figure out what column number `BC` is.  I did have the verification in my code originally but then removed it because I couldn't think of a scenario that the find wouldn't work -  `checknum` comes from a combobox that is populated with the column being searched.  But thank you none-the-less.  I'm sure there will be a time this method will come in handy.